# HtmlAgilityPack - Select descendant until element with class

Tags: c#, dom, xpath, nodes, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack in my C# application to scrape some HTML code. But I'm having issues selecting a particular tag.

This is the HTML that I have:

```
<div class="Post">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Alt Text">
    <br>
    <b>THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT</b>
    <div class="DesktopElements">
        <br>
        Hello world
    </div>
    <br>
    Some text here.
    <br>
    <b>Title</b>
    <br>
    Some more text here.
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to select the text inside the first "b"-tag: `<b>THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT</b>`, but only if it's before the div with class "DesktopElements". I do not want to select anything after the "DesktopElements" class.
This works fine if the `<b>` tag is present there. But the issue is, that sometimes this `<b>` tag will not be present.

What I've been trying so far is to get the first `<b>` descendant of `<div class="Post">`, but as you might realize, it will not work if the  tag is not present. Sometimes it's there, sometimes it's not there.

So I basically need to only check for a `<b>` tag between `<div class="Post">` and `<div class="DesktopElements">` and select the first (and only) `<b>` in there.

How can I do that?

In other words, sometimes it can look like this:

```
<div class="Post">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Alt Text">
    <br>
    <div class="DesktopElements">
        <br>
        Hello world
    </div>
    <br>
    Some text here.
    <br>
    <b>Title</b>
    <br>
    Some more text here.
</div>
```

And if that's the case, I just set the "p.Title" to "none".

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
p.Title = row.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='Post']").Descendants("b").Select(title => title.InnerText).Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)).ToList().First();
```

This will capture the first `<b>` tag's InnerText value, but if there is no "b"-tag before `<div class="DesktopElements">`, it will instead select the `<b>` tag below which says `<b>Title</b>` which is not what I want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-8.0) to only get the nodes before `<div class="DesktopElements">` instead of only getting `Descendants("b")`:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='Post']")
    .Descendants()
    .TakeWhile(node => !node.HasClass("DesktopElements"))
    .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name == "b");

p.Title = node?.InnerText ?? "none";
```

See [example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LkwW4F).

Comment: THANK YOU! I managed to get it to work. First it returned some empty strings but that was due to me being stupid. THANK YOU!! It works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want this XPath:

```
//div[@class='Post']/div[@class='DesktopElements']/preceding-sibling::b
```

This wil select only those `b` that become before `div[@class='DesktopElements']` and are child of `div[@class='Post']`

**EDIT**

After looking at the shared url(in a comment that is not there anymore?), I noticed there are no classes `Post` and `DesktopElements`.
Instead there were the classes: `PostText` and `ForumDesktopElements`

No idea how that is possible but if that is the case, you would need this XPath

```
//div[@class='PostText']/div[@class='ForumDesktopElements']/preceding-sibling::b
```